# How should a Firebase Firestore database be structured to efficiently store grouped data?

Tags: firebase, performance, google-cloud-firestore, structure

If I'm building a dashboard to browse through a list of messages associated with a given topic, and the number of messages posted to that topic can grow in an unbounded fashion, should I store the messageIDs within a subcollection under each topicID document, with the messages themselves in a separate root-level collection? Or should the messages be stored as documents themselves in a nested sub collection within the topic?

The messages also need to be organized by userID, so I was planning on having the following database structure with separate root-level collections:

- topics (root-level collection)

  - topicID (document)

    - messages (collection)

      - messageId0 (empty document)
      - messageId1 (empty document)
      - messageId2 (empty document)
- users (root-level collection)

  - userID (document)

    - messages (collection)

      - messageId0 (empty document)
      - messageId1 (empty document)
      - messageId2 (empty document)
- messages (root-level collection)

  - messageId0 (document with message fields)
  - messageId1 (document with message fields)
  - messageId2 (document with message fields)

How will performance be impacted as the number of messages posted grows? Will I be able to efficiently display all messages for a given topic, as well as all messages for a given user? Is there a better way to structure this data?

If the dashboard needs to show a particular topic's messages ordered by some field (such as timestamp), would this be an inefficient database structure, since we would need to query for all of the topic's messages, then order by a field inside of a document inside a separate collection?

Comment: Your data model seems to respect the hierarchical and subcollections approach as defined on the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#hierarchical-data). Be aware you don't reach these [limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) and consider using [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) in order to get your data in batches for more efficiency.

Comment: Indexing fields with monotonically increasing fields such as timestamps can lead to [hotspots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#indexes) and decreased performance. [High read, writes and deletes to such narrow document ranges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#high_read_write_and_delete_rates_to_a_narrow_document_range) are best to be avoided. Consider using [sharded timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/shard-timestamp) to avoid this kind of issues for timestamp based fields.

Comment: This following [series of videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ) released by the Firebase team make a good job explaining the points I made (I recommend you to watch #4 specifically for data modelling).

Comment: This is way too broad a question to be answerable. #1 First thing about Firebase is that a data structure is dependent on the queries you want to run against it. In your question, there's topics, users, and messages. I don't see any reason why your topic doesn't have message documents and then each message has a userID field. That would eliminate unnecessary data duplication. Why do you want to use *nested sub collections*? What defines *inefficient database structure*? See - too big a question. Write some code, read and write some data and when you get stuck with *that*, post a question.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, your response was super helpful. After watching all of the videos in the tutorial series you linked, I’ve decided to go with a root-level collection structure with composite indexes for the composite ordered queries I would need to make.